# what is View.getDrawingTime()?

Tags: android

I'd like to use View.getDrawingTime(), however, I am confused as to the value the function returns.

in my app, `getDrawingTime()` returns something along the lines of 545366733
Compared to `System.currentTimeMillis()` I see 1375750319462

The documentation is fairly inadequate in this case :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingTime()

How can I compare the value I get from getDrawingTime() to currentTimeMillise() (or something similar) ?

I desire to know the time difference between now and the last time the view was drawn.

Thanks !!

Comment: Hmm, well in milliseconds that's about 6.3 days. When was the last time your phone booted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't dig far enough to be 100% certain, but I got to 99.7%.

Both [`scheduleDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scheduleDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) and the internal [`fadeStartTime`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java#9029) use the `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` clock. My guess is that `getDrawingTime()` does too.

Note that [`SystemClock.uptimeMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29) does not count time when in deep sleep. So, if you're trying to time events between sessions, you might want to try something else.

An alternative is to override your View's `onDraw()` and set your own timer, but it's up to what you need, really.

Comment: `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` is indeed correct. I checked: View.getDrawingTime() returned 601423378 and `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` returned 601445559. Thankyou !!